# Print common elements of two lists with two nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I'm new to python and I have this code that programs to print out the intersection between two sequences.

the code works fine, but I'm trying to convert it into nested loops kind of code. I tried many things, but non worked, could you please help me?

here is the code

```
print("This program finds the common elements of two lists")

sequenceOne = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the first list: ")
sequenceTwo = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the second list: ")

sequenceOne = sequenceOne.split()
sequenceTwo = sequenceTwo.split()
listOfIntersection = []

for i in sequenceOne:
     if i in sequenceTwo:
         sequenceTwo.remove(i)
         listOfIntersection.append(i)

print('The intersection of these two lists is {' +(", ".join(str(i) for i in listOfIntersection))+'}')
```

Output:

```
This program finds the intersection of two sets
Please enter the space-separated elements of the first set: 12 k e 34 1.5 12 hi 12 0.2
Please enter the space-separated elements of the second set: 1.5 hi 12 0.1 54 12 hi hi hi
The intersection of these two sets is {12, 1.5, 12, hi}
```

Comment: check my new answer, is that what you want ?

Comment: if it works, it is better not try to use nested loops. The proposed answer with set(...) is very good and easy/better way to handle this with Python.

Comment: @Malo I know this is much cleaner, but its an assignment, and its about nested loops 

Comment: @MMSS19 you should edit and state this. Easy way is to replace "if i in sequenceTwo:" by the second for loop "for j in sequenceTwo:" ...

Comment: output is really strange, how do you define if a duplicate needs to be kept or not ? I count 3x12 in first set, 4x'hi' in second set, but the answer has 2x 12 and 1x hi .. could you explain ?

Comment: @Malo there are two ```12```  because the same number occurs twice in sequence one and sequence two. ```hi``` occurs only once in sequence one, so it only intersects once with sequence two. think of it like connecting dots, where the same dot connects only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code with nested for loops, which keeps duplicated values.

```
print("This program finds the intersection of two sets")

sequenceOne = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the first set: ")
sequenceTwo = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the second set: ")

sequenceOne = sequenceOne.split()
sequenceTwo = sequenceTwo.split()
listOfIntersection = []

for i in sequenceOne:
     for j in sequenceTwo:
         if (i==j):
             listOfIntersection.append(i)

print('The intersection of these two sets is {' +(", ".join(str(i) for i in listOfIntersection))+'}')
```

Here is second solution, which mimics exactly what you did first:

```
print("This program finds the intersection of two sets")

sequenceOne = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the first set: ")
sequenceTwo = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the second set: ")

sequenceOne = sequenceOne.split()
sequenceTwo = sequenceTwo.split()
listOfIntersection = []

for i in sequenceOne:
     for j in sequenceTwo:
         if (i==j):
             listOfIntersection.append(i)
             sequenceTwo.remove(i)
             break
    

print('The intersection of these two sets is {' +(", ".join(str(i) for i in listOfIntersection))+'}')
```

Comment: Thank you @Malo. I appreciate you help a lot

Comment: Second solution gives you exact ouput ... but it is really really far fetch assignment ;)

Comment: I know, they are very particular about using the method they suggest. which it kinda of stupid.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("This program finds the intersection of two sets")

sequenceOne = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the first set: ").split()
sequenceTwo = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the second set: ").split()

print (set(sequenceOne).intersection(sequenceTwo))
```

the `intersection()` method returns the intersection between the two sets `sequenceOne` and `sequenceTwo`

Comment: the problems with ```set()``` is that it removes duplicates. and as you see from the example 12 is duplicated, as it occurs twice

Comment: then sorry, the only ways i know of are using `sets` and the method `intersection()` because intersection is commonly understood and used with sets and they remove duplicates, or by `list comprehension` in my other answer, or using your way of `for loops` and probably the best way to do exactly what you are looking for is my other answer. there is a way to go around sets, which is  adding keys to keep duplicates but it is not efficient in this problem i guess.

Comment: Thats ok, thank you for trying and for your help. its very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
print("This program finds the intersection of two sets")

sequenceOne = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the first set: ").split()
sequenceTwo = input("Please enter the space-separated elements of the second set: ").split()

listOfIntersection = [x for x in sequenceOne if x in sequenceTwo]

print('The intersection of these two sets is {' +(", ".join(str(i) for i in listOfIntersection))+'}')
```

this line replaces the nested `for` loop and condition that you have and creates your list of intersection : `listOfIntersection = [x for x in sequenceOne if x in sequenceTwo]`

Comment: This is considered a nested loop? and thank you for your help

Comment: this is list comprehension .. ask you teacher if he accepts this ;)